# javascript active class different color on specific page

Tags: javascript, navbar

How can I make ".active" class be different color that will be specific by page name; for example ".active_index" and hover color of all links in ".navbar" will be the same as ".active_index"? 
I use include php option for header (include('header.php');).
Heres my code:

**HTML CODE**

```
<nav>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li id="pageIndex"><a href="index.php">Početna</a></li>
    <li id="pageZeolit"><a href="zeolit.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>Zeolit</a></li>
    <li id="pageIzodenko"><a href="izodeko.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Izodeko</a></li>
    <li id="pageElektronika"><a href="elektronika.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Elektronika</a></li>
    <li id="pageInformacije"><a href="informacije.php">O nama</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
if (pageName == 'index.php') {
    active_index.setAttribute(color, red);
}
```

Comment: If you are looking to do this in js then you will have to grab the url and then parse it so you can get the page name. When adding the active class, just attach the page name to the end of it. In css, define the classes for each page so the colour is different

Comment: @Huangism I'll try to do that.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you can get the page name in php. If you can do that then you just add the page name as a class to the `body` for example and define your css hover class based on the body class

Comment: @Huangism Look the js

Comment: I don't know how your active class gets added but that js does not look right

Comment: To clarify, you want a hover `color` value based on the url, not the same color for any "active" link?

Comment: @BDawg so if you go on index.php, active color is for example white (Active is "Početna"), while hover color of all links in navbar is white too ( Zeolit, Izodeko, Elektronika, O nama) .
If you go on "zeolit.php", active color is for example green (Active is "Zeolit"), while hover color of all links in navbar is green too (Početna, Izodeko, Elektronika, O nama) .

Comment: @L.Grgincic Ahh, that explanation was perfect. I understand what you are trying to do now. I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: @BDawg Thank you, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PHP logic can probably be improved, but here is an idea...

First, use PHP to get the HTTP request URI, and add a class to the `<html>` or `<body>` tag. (ex. `<html class="index-page">` Then, use that class in a CSS selector that applies to both active and hovered list items (ex. `.index-page .navbar a:hover` and `.index-page .navbar li.active > a`). Finally, apply your `active` class in the `header.php` file - again, using the HTTP request URI.

**page.php**

```
<?php
  // Get $pageClass (ex. "index-page" or "zeolit-page")
  $uri = preg_replace('/^\//', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if(strlen($uri) === 0) { $uri = 'index.php'; }
  $pageClass = str_replace('.php', '-page', $uri);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="<?php echo $pageClass; ?>">
<head>
  ...
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <?php include('header.php'); ?>
  ...
```

**style.css**

```
.index-page .navbar a:hover,
.index-page .navbar li.active > a { color: white; }

.zeolit-page .navbar a:hover,
.zeolit-page .navbar li.active > a { color: green; }

...
```

**header.php**

```
<?php $activeClass = 'active'; ?>
<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php' ? $activeClass : '') ?>" id="pageIndex">
        <a href="index.php">Početna</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/zeolit.php' ? $activeClass : '') ?>" id="pageZeolit">
        <a href="zeolit.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>Zeolit</a>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Alternatively, you could use page-specific styles in their own CSS files. This could be placed below a default CSS file to override/customize the default page styles. Again, the PHP logic can be improved here, but you could do this, for example...

```
<head>
  ...
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') { // this is "index.php" ?>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/zeolit.php') { ?>
    <link href="zeolit.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php } ?>
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: Or you can just add a class to body based on the page and declare all styles in a global or common style sheet

Comment: @Huangism Yes. Thanks for adding that!

Comment: If there's a good reason this answer was down-voted, I would appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @BDawg Btw I didn't down-vote, but I think your answer is not giving me the right thing. There is no :hover color.

Comment: @L.Grgincic I wasn't aware you were having difficulty with the CSS part, too. I'll come up with a more complete answer for you.

Comment: @L.Grgincic Answer updated. Let me know if that still doesn't help

Comment: @BDawg This is the right thing I needed! Thank you for your time on solving this for me! Much appreciated!